# use python requests to sign in github with the correct style but the response's status_code is 422?

Tags: python, github, python-requests

so,I would like to do some practice,sign in github by requests,I think I use the correct style to post,but when I post data to 'https://github.com/session', the response's status_code is 422,it means semantics mistake,I never meet this problem,can someone help me?

```
# 尝试GitHub登陆
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from lxml import html
#✓
class Login:
    def __init__(self):
        self.headers = {
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/'
            'webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
            'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0',
            'Host': 'github.com'
        }
        self.post_url = 'https://github.com/session'
        self.login_url = 'https://github.com/login'
        self.session = requests.Session()

    def token(self):
        response = self.session.get(self.login_url, headers=self.headers)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            token = re.findall(r'name="authenticity_token" value="(.*?)">', response.text)
            if token:
                return token[0]
        else:
            print('链接失败')
            return None

    def login(self, email, password):
        token = self.token()
        print(type(token))
        data = {
            'commit': 'Sign in',
            'utf8': '✓',
            'authenticity_token': token,
            'login': email,
            'password': password,
            'webauthn - support': 'supported'
        }
        response = self.session.post(self.post_url, data=data)
        print(response.status_code)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        ul = soup.find(name='ul')
        if ul:
            for li in ul.find_all('li'):
                spans = li.find_all('span')
                for span in spans:
                    print(span.text)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    login = Login()
    login.login(email,password)
```

when you print the response.status_code, show 422,

Comment: What's your goal in doing this? This endpoint isn't meant to be scripted, so there's probably a better way to achieve your goal.

Comment: thank for you reply,i am not good at English,so maybe describe is not clear.I mean,my goal is to write a python script to sign in github,use the third party wrap 'requests', but when I executed the sentence ' response = self.session.post(self.post_url, data=data)' ,the response.status_code is 422,

Comment: could you please explain the better way?

Comment: If you want to issue commands or get data from GitHub in a programmatic way, you should use the [API](https://developer.github.com) (probably the v3 REST API).

Comment: right,although I want to practice to use requests post,API is a better way. thanks